# ExceptionHandler not catching all uncaught exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I have built a simple ExceptionHandler class:

```
class ExceptionHandler{

    public function __construct(){

        set_exception_handler(array($this, 'handleException'));
    }

    public function handleException(\Exception $exception){
        echo $exception->getMessage() . $exception->getLine() .  $exception->getFile());

    }
}
```

The `ExceptionHandler` object is created at the earliest possible moment during processing. A Session component which uses the database for storing it's data is constructed shortly after the ExceptionHandler.

The session component sets the following to properly close a sessions when APC is used:

```
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

I then performed a test by shutting down my MySQL server and running the application. What is puzzling is that the exception is caught by `ExceptionHandler`, but at the same time remains uncaught and is outputted by xdebug:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] ????,??????????? at line 133 in RedBean_Driver_PDO.php. //This is generated by my exception handler

//These were uncaught and processed by Xdebug
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'PDO::__construct() [133

( ! ) Exception: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] ????,??????????? (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in RedBean_Driver_PDO.php on line 133

Call Stack
//Call stack
```

What could be causing this? My understanding is that the `ExceptionHandler` should be able to catch ALL uncaught exceptions except any exceptions that is thrown within the `ExceptionHandler`.

Update:
I have a feeling that this has to deal with `session_write_close` which is called on shutdown. session_write_close needs access to the database, but the database is unavaliable. An exception is then thrown. Since script execution has ended, `ExceptionHandler` is unavaliable, so we get an uncaught exception. Are there anyways around this?

I am running php 5.3.9 as fcgi on apache 2.2 using mod_cgi on a windows 7 machine.

A stack trace:

```
#   Time    Memory  Function
1   2.0323  767336  ExceptionHandler->handleException( ) //Initial exception caught + handled
2   2.0334  773968  Session->write( ) //Script shutdown started (session_write_close to database)
3   2.0335  774344  Database->findOne( )
4   2.0335  774640  Database->__call( )
5   2.0335  774728  call_user_func_array( )
6   2.0335  775016  RedBean_Facade::findOne( )
7   2.0335  775016  RedBean_Facade::find( )
8   2.0335  775384  RedBean_OODB->find( )
9   2.0335  775384  RedBean_QueryWriter_AQueryWriter->selectRecord( )
10  2.0335  775448  RedBean_QueryWriter_AQueryWriter->safeTable( )
11  2.0335  775536  RedBean_QueryWriter_AQueryWriter->check( )
12  2.0335  775536  RedBean_Adapter_DBAdapter->escape( )
13  2.0335  775536  RedBean_Driver_PDO->Escape( )
14  2.0335  775536  RedBean_Driver_PDO->connect( )
15  2.0336  776200  PDO->__construct( ) //Cannot connect to database
16  4.0433  782768  ErrorHandler->handleError( ) //Error converted to exception
```

I have a feeling that this cannot be really avoided, and in a production environment `display_errors` will be turned off anyway. However, I am not exactly satisfied with this solution as it seems to not be very 'clean'.

Comment: This may not fix your problem but you might try correcting this code `$exception-> getFile());` by removing the space so that it reads `$exception->getFile());`

Comment: Wrap the offending code inside try/catch and check what the current exception handler is when the PDO exception is thrown. Maybe some other component reset the exception handler behind your back?

Comment: @rdlowrey: Fix it, although that was just a typo when I was writing the question. @Jon: Tried wrapping the code in a try/catch and was able to silence the exception. Checked the exception handler, and it was still `ExceptionHandler` that was being used.  I have explicitly added `exit()` into `handleException()` but it seems like those uncaught exceptions are still being outputted after `exit()`!

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch fatal exceptions in PHP. Sadly! Register a shutdown function which flushes the output buffer is all you can do. Since you already have a shutdown function then something in there is causing the problem. I would try this:

```
// This must be called before any code is executed
register_shutdown_function( 'shutdownFunction' );

function shutdownFunction() {
    // process code - be careful not to throw another fatal exception
    try {
        call_user_func( 'session_write_close' );
    } catch() {}
    ob_clean();
}
```

... other than that I think you're stuck